# How can I pass body params in a Next.js rewrite?

Tags: authentication, next.js, url-rewriting, identityserver4, body-parser

I have this `POST` request:

```
const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
          grant_type: "password",
          client_id: "client",
          client_secret: "clientsecret",
          username: "matias@gmail.com",
          password: "12341234" 
      })
    };

    const token = fetch("http://localhost:3000/connect/token", requestOptions)
                    .then(response => console.log(response))
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I would like to rewrite it so I can bypass CORS error in development environment. To achieve this, I have this code in my `next.config.js` file:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  async rewrites() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? [
          {
            source: "/connect/token",
            destination: "http://localhost:4446/connect/token",
          }
        ]
      : [];
  },
}
```

How can I specify the body params (`grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username` and `password`) to this Next.js rewrite? The error I am getting suggest these values are not present in my rewrite:

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator[0]
      No client identifier found
```

Comment: The body should be passed without specific configuration. Have you tried making the request like `fetch("/api/connect/token", requestOptions)`, then changing the rewrite source to `/api/connect/token`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Next.js, but have you tried to add the url to the client configuration as [Allowed Cors Origins](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html?highlight=cors)?

You could add in your develop client the url `http://localhost:3000`.